# If and Else Statements Bug

Tags: javascript, html

I have been learning some basic JavaScript lately and have run into a problem.  My Code looks like this:

```
<html>
     <body>
          <script type="text/javascript">
                 var name= window.prompt("Type Your Name.")
                 if ( (name=='Ethan') )
                    document.write("You LOVE BACON!!!")
                 else
                     document.write("You Have not entered your name in yet.")
          </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that when I run the code and enter my name the page will say this:

> You LOVE BACON!!!You have not entered your name yet.

My else statement appears with my if statement as well.

Comment: I tested it and everything works fine for me

Comment: Where do I put the semicolons?  I am sorry this is probably all elementary to you but I have just started with JavaScript.

Comment: Seems to work fine in JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/psuxr/

Comment: Mabye it is my web browser or something.  Not sure though.

Comment: @EthanBacon: I run the fiddles in IE9, latest FF and Chrome, which browser are you using?

Comment: You should have semicolons at the end of every line, except immediately after the `if` and `else`, which would normally be followed by blocks in curly braces. But that doesn't seem to be what is causing the problem.

Comment: Weird... do you have something that is messing w/ your javascript or disabling it? that's really odd!! Also - do you happen to have another browser you can test?

Comment: I just feel the need to comment that I don't think you deserve a downvote, even if this is a very basic question, and it's probably a minor misstake. Your wording is nice and you post some code showing effort and what it is that goes wrong. Keep it up!

Comment: I agree 100% with Daniel

Comment: (perhaps pointing out the obvious), but JavaScript string comparisons are case-sensitive. When you enter your name into the prompt, are you proper-casing it?

Comment: It doesn't deserve a downvote but without a working example showing the problem, it's rather hard to troubleshoot/answer.

Comment: And that's why you always use semicolons `;` and `{` braces `}` to clearly structure statements. Get used to it from the beginning, omitting them brings no good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if ( name=='Ethan' ) //see here
                    document.write("You LOVE BACON!!!");      // Function Call!
                 else
                     document.write("You Have not entered your name in yet."); //
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
     <body>
          <script type="text/javascript">
                 var name = window.prompt("Type Your Name."); // Assignment!
                 if ( name=='Ethan' )
                    document.write("You LOVE BACON!!!");      // Function Call!
                 else
                     document.write("You Have not entered your name in yet."); // Function Call!
          </script>
     </body>
</html>
```

Semi-colons go at the end of each statement, after every function call or assignment in this case.